# jQuery to PHP - serialized strings

Tags: php, jquery, string, codeigniter, serialization

I'm currently AJAX'ing a login form.

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
```

This is the data I'm sending, I get this with PHP using Codeigniter like so:

```
$ajax = $this->input->post('data');
```

This returns `username=john&password=doe` as you'd expect.

How do I turn that into an array? I've tried doing `unserialize()` and I get null.

Comment: possibly answer of your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3817220/388053)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use PHP's `parse_str()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

```
<?php
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
parse_str($str);
echo $first;  // value
echo $arr[0]; // foo bar
echo $arr[1]; // baz

parse_str($str, $output);
echo $output['first'];  // value
echo $output['arr'][0]; // foo bar
echo $output['arr'][1]; // baz

?>
```

Using your code it would be:

```
parse_str($this->input->post('data'), $ajax);
echo $ajax['username'] . "/" . $ajax['password'];
```

Comment: Maybe give it another try, I just tried the demo and it worked as expected.

Comment: Eugh, it was a typo on my `parse_str` before!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is with `parse_str`;

```
parse_str($ajax, $array);
$array === array('username'=>'john', 'password'=>'doe');
```

However, the way you send your ajax data is a bit odd. Why are you serializing to a formencoded string and sending that string as a value to the 'data' parameter? Why don't you just send it directly?  Then you could use `$this->input->post('username') === 'john'` without the extra level of deserializing.

For example, do this:

```
$.post(url, $(form).serialize());
```

instead of this (which you seem to be doing:

```
$.post(url, {data:$(form).serialize()});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use parse_str()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$parameters = array();

foreach ( explode( '&', $ajax ) as $parameterAndValue ) {
    list ( $parameter, $value ) = explode( '=', $parameterAndValue );
    $parameters[$parameter] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guest we could use normal request, it's defend on the request type from ajax, using GET or POST, and then in the php we could use like normal post, like `$_POST['username']` or `$_GET['username']` we don't have to use function to unserialize that, and for validation using CI just call like normal use, `$this->input->post('username')`,am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use as follows

```
<?php $username = $this->input->post('username');?>
<?php $password= $this->input->post('password');?>
```

You can do anything with above variables