# Deserialize Response

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I am try to post a data from a from I have this code on my html.

```
<javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnsubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var testData = $("#test").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxSurvey.php",             
        data: {survey:testData}          
    });
});
})
</javascript>
```

and my form

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="POST">
  <input name="surveyperiod" id="surveyperiod" type="date">
  <input name="deadline" id="deadline" type="date"  >
  <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit"name="btnsubmit" value="   Update    ">
</form>
```

and my php page

```
if(isset($_POST['survey']){
    $myDate = $_POST['survey'];

    mysql_query('INSERT INTO (surveyperiod,deadline) VALUES (????????)');

}
```

Now how can I deserialize $myDate which is look like below

> surveyperiod=2014-02-25&deadline=2014-02-18

Comment: mysql_* functions have been deprecated. Please use PDO or mysqli instead!

Comment: This ir pretty the same questions with good answeres: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603/how-do-i-php-unserialize-a-jquery-serialized-form

Comment: it should be corrected from script itself, not from PHP dcript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tricky method is use [parse_str()](https://www.php.net/parse_str)

```
// Access as Variable
if( isset($_POST['survey']) ){

    // surveyperiod=2014-02-25&deadline=2014-02-18
    parse_str($_POST['survey']);

    $S_Period = $surveyperiod;
    $S_Deadline = $deadline;

   // do whatever you want
   mysql_query('INSERT INTO (surveyperiod,deadline) VALUES ( "'.$S_Period.'", "'.$S_Deadline.'" )');

}
```

### Explanation:

In you Ajax Request you send the data via POST method( `data: {survey:testData}` ) and assigned a POST variable that is `survey` and this POST variables contains the data string `surveyperiod=2014-02-25&deadline=2014-02-18` as you assigned in your javascript `testData`. Now what we have to do is, Now we have to parse string into variables and parse_str() inbuilt function do it for you. That's it :)

Comment: jogesh_pi, it's so tricky that I can't understand :). Thank you so much. This solves my problem.

Comment: @jules I explain it, now hope you understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to deserialize, you can do that in different way by putting hidden field like;

**HTML:**

```
<form id="test" name="test" method="POST">
  <input name="survey" type="hidden" value="true"/>
  <input name="surveyperiod" id="surveyperiod" type="date">
  <input name="deadline" id="deadline" type="date"  >
  <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit"name="btnsubmit" value="   Update    ">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['survey']){
    $myDate = $_POST['survey'];

    mysql_query('INSERT INTO (surveyperiod,deadline) VALUES ($_POST["surveyperiod"], $_POST["deadline"])');

}
```

**JS:**

```
<javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnsubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var testData = $("#test").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxSurvey.php",             
        data: testData          
    });
});
})
</javascript>
```

By doing this, you dont neede to post data like `{survey:testData}`. Simply add,

```
<input name="survey" type="hidden" value="true"/>
```

html and check hidden field on php side. If a field with name `survey` exists, then run your code