# How to get two forms on one submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have two forms that look like this:

```html
<h2>First form</h2>
<form id="first-form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="left[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="right[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="left[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="right[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="left[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="right[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="left[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="right[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<!-- some more HTML -->
<h2>Second form</h2>
<form id="second-form">
  <label>
    <input type="search" name="sentence" value="i like the bananas">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="parse-as" value="S">
  </label>
  <label>
    <select name="include-features">
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option selected="selected">No</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    <select name="show-earley">
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option selected="selected">No</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Parse</button>
</form>
```

Note that the first form can contain more rows; the user can add more rows to the form. As you can see, there's only one submit button. That's because both forms have to be submitted together. In jQuery I'd do something like this:

```
$("#second-form").submit(function(event) {
  $("first-form").submit();
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

As the front-end developer of the team, I need to pass down the values of both forms to the back-end. Unfortunately I'm at loss how to do this. I figured I could do something like this:

```
$("#second-form").on("submit", function(event) {
  $("#first-form").submit();
  $.post("php/do.php", $("#second-form").serialize());
  event.preventDefault();
});

$("#first-form").on("submit", function(event) {
  $.post("php/do.php", $("#first-form").serializeArray());
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

`.serializeArray()` seems necessary because of the array-like values in the HTML for `#first-form`. In the second form, however, we don't need an array. The issue I'm having now is, what code do I need in `do.php` that can handle the input. How do you access the data, i.e. the serialized forms in PHP?

I tried a number of things such as

```
<?php
$data = parse_str($_POST["right[]"]);
var_dump($data);
$date1 = parse_str($_POST["right[][0]"]);
var_dump($data);
$data2 = parse_str($_POST["right[][1]"]);
var_dump($data);
?>
```

But all of these return an `Undefined index` error, which seems to mean that my "selector" is wrong. How would I go about selecting the array from the first form, and the values of the second form in PHP? And is my jQuery method of submitting `first-form` together with the second correct?

Comment: you will have to combine the forms or use ajax. you can't submit 2 html forms like that.

Comment: @DanielA.White could you elaborate on that in an answer? Merging the forms is not an option.

Comment: @DanielA.White Please reopen. This is *not* a duplicate as I am asking how to access the content in PHP whereas the linked question isn't concerned with PHP access. Of importance is that one form is an array (`serializeArray`) and the other isn't. The linked question doesn't even talk about PHP access. Please reopen.

Comment: @BramVanroy I think your question might already have an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603/how-do-i-php-unserialize-a-jquery-serialized-form

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this :

```html
<h2>First form</h2>
<form id="first-form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="left[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="right[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="left[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="right[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="left[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="right[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="left[]" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="right[]" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <!-- some more HTML -->
  <h2>Second form</h2>
  <label>
    <input type="search" name="sentence" value="i like the bananas">
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="parse-as" value="S">
  </label>
  <label>
    <select name="include-features">
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option selected="selected">No</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <label>
    <select name="show-earley">
      <option>Yes</option>
      <option selected="selected">No</option>
    </select>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Parse</button>
</form>
```

Maybe it's not the cleanest way to do it, but it's the easier. Just get the results with :

```
<?php
$data = parse_str($_POST["right[]"]);
var_dump($data);
$date1 = parse_str($_POST["right[][0]"]);
var_dump($data1);
$data2 = parse_str($_POST["right[][1]"]);
var_dump($data2);
?>
```