# Unable to access array indexes received via jQuery.serialize()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Alright, I'm trying to get form values via `jQuery serialize`. Here's my jQuery code.

```
$("#add_cus_button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'ajax.php?requestid=14',
        data:{postdata:$("form#addnew").serialize()},
        success: function(response)
        {

        }
    })
});
```

Here's my PHP :-

```
$postdata = explode('&', $_POST['postdata']);
var_dump($postdata);
```

This results into this :-

[image]

Now if I try to access a field called `customer_name`, I do this.

```
echo $postdata['requestid'];
```

But this throws undefined index error. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Akshay, either turn `xdebug` off, or please post the output as HTML. The `alert` is worthless. Just show us what's there in the Network tab?

Comment: Is 'requestid' really the way to access your customer_name?  It sounds like your PHP is getting an undefined index error because it should be `$postdata['customer_name']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

```
data: $("form#addnew").serialize()
```

This already is a serialized version. You don't need to add `{key: serialized_value}`. Or if you really wanna use a `data` object, use `serializeArray()` and send it to the PHP, but in the PHP, don't use the below line:

```
$postdata = explode('&', $_POST['postdata']); // Don't use this.
```

Comment: Damn! I wanted this, just used an extra variable to send the data. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1):

`.seriliaze()` will return you a `string` `like a=something&b=whatever...` and which works in a GET Request, and not a `array` or `object` which you need in a POST request.

To make it return an array use `.serializeArray()` but even `serializeArray` wont work in a POST request. So you need to use something like `.serializeObject()`.

Something like this:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};
```

Comment: Not sure who downvoted. I feel it frustrating if someone downvotes without any reason.

Answer (score 0):

**1st:** you need to use

```
data:$("form#addnew").serialize(),
```

**2nd:** if this serialize looks like this

```
"varname=val&var2=val2"
```

in php

```
<?php
   echo $_POST["varname"];
   echo $_POST["var2"];
 ?>
```

take a look at [How do I PHP-unserialize a jQuery-serialized form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603/how-do-i-php-unserialize-a-jquery-serialized-form)