# How to send all current post data in jQuery AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, api

So I'm working on a site and I am setting up a register system, and I want the site to take all of the current `POST` data `(after the request was made)` and send the current `POST` data in an `AJAX` call, like:

```
$.post('/api/post', {
  "type":"register",
  "pdata":POST_DATA
}, function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

And have the `PHP Backend` be able to take in the `$_POST['pdata']` and use that as the data it's going to use, just to make the transfer safer and easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use  [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

You can send all your form data

```
$.post('/api/post', {
  "type":"register",
  "pdata":$('.your_form_class_name').serialize()
}, function(data){
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: So instead of submitting the form, just send the form data to the api instead? Saves time I guess `:)` let me try this one second

Comment: @Jek an also i think you may want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603/how-do-i-php-unserialize-a-jquery-serialized-form