# cannot submit data in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model, controller

i m trying to submit data using this code in codeigniter but can't submit data and create error.

> error:POST http://localhost/managment/index.php/welcome/add 500 (Internal Server Error)

signupform is id of my sign up form which contain 6 fields and have a submit button

**ajax** i saved this file with .js extension

```
$(document).on("submit", "#signupform", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //var view_id=$("#id_hid").val();
    //alert(view_id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",

        data: $('#signupform').serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "../welcome/add",
        success: function (data)
        {
            //var json=$.parseJSON(data);
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**controller**

```
public function add() {
    //$data=array();
    $postData = array();
    //prepare post data
    $postData = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'mobileno' => $this->input->post('mobileno'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address')
    );

    // //insert post data

    $insert = $this->home_model->insert_form($postData);
    $data['msg'] = "data insert successfully";
    echo json_encode($data['msg']);
}
```

**model**

```
function insert_form($data)
{   
    $insert=$this->db->insert('emp',$data);
    if($insert)
    {
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    //echo  json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: whats error in the network tab when you submit it ??

Comment: Have you tried displaying the data in the console??

Comment: @DeadManAlive error: jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/managment//index.php/welcome/add 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @Prabhu no,i don't know how to do that

Comment: Add this before ajax `console.log($('#signupform').serialize());`

Comment: @Prabhu yes,data is showing in console.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your console in your question??

Comment: Open Chrome Dev tools. Click `network` and submit the form, then click the post url in the network tab (should be the last request) and hit `preview`

Comment: Because of the form serializing you are getting an error. I feel so!!

Answer (score 2):

Your Javascript Ajax function

```
      var frmData = $('#signupform').serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type:"post",

        data:{frmData:frmData},
        dataType: "JSON",
        url:"<?php echo base_url('index.php/your_controller_name/your_function_name')?>",       
        success:function(data)
         {

          }
        });
```

Your controller function

```
   public function add()
   {
        $postData=array();
        parse_str($this->input->post('frmData'),$postData);

        //prepare post data
        $postData = array(
            'username' => $postData['username'],
            'password' => $postData['password'],
            'email' => $postData['email'],
            'mobileno' => $postData['mobileno'],
            'address' => $postData['address']
        );       
   }
```

When you use serialize in java script  then you must retrieve data using parse_str function of php then you will get exact post data from encoded string .

Comment: I've never had to use `parse_str` with serialized data from js.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in error ***error: jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/managment//index.php/welcome/add*** you can see worng direction of URL

**Whats wrong**

```
http://localhost/managment//index.php/welcome/add  
                          ^^
```

**WHat should I can do for this**

`Change url:"../welcome/add",` to `url:"http://localhost/managment/index.php/welcome/add",` `

or

```
var base = <?php echo base_url() ?>
url: base+"index.php/welcome/add"
```

**Make sure**

In `application/config.php` base Url should be `http://localhost/managment/`

Read **[How do I PHP-unserialize a jQuery-serialized form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603/how-do-i-php-unserialize-a-jquery-serialized-form)**

Comment: you need to check form serialization  as well

Comment: its post request change `type: "POST",`