# Unserialize data from a jquery ajax from and send email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a very long form in a php template, all data are send by a jquery ajax in `serialize` mode to a php page to send an email.

I have this problem: How I can `unserialize` the data in the php page, and send them by email ?

The php template is completed with different data. So I can't use for each fields just urldecode in this way `$nome = urldecode($_POST['nome']);`

I have to find a way for take all the data arrive in the php page and send them in an email. I read about `parse_str` But I don't know if can works and how use it.

At moment this is my ajax code:

```
var datiform = $("#FormWorkspace").serialize();    

$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: ".../form-cf/engine.php",
          data: datiform,
          dataType: "html",
        success: function(datiform)
            {
          alert("success" + datiform);
            },
        error: function()
            {
          alert("no success " + datiform);
            }
        });
```

Comment: you'd use parse_str like this: `parse_str($_POST['data'], $myPostVar)` and then you can use `$myPostVar` like `$_POST` - `$myPostVar['name']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603/how-do-i-php-unserialize-a-jquery-serialized-form

Comment: Thank you @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs in this way I have to write  `$myPostVar['name']` for each fields? can I make a loop for generate automatically the data?

Comment: @ajax yes I was reading this, but if i make echo `json_encode($data);` it will return all the data? but for send it in the email, I have to add one by one. no?

Comment: [Have you read this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3817220/2569323)

Comment: You can `loop` over `$_POST`.

Comment: thank you @AjAX. ok I start to understand that i can use ` $params = array(); parse_str($_GET, $params);`  like in the post,  but I don't have clear how I can use it, and how sue for send the email. How I can extract the data make the loop and send it by email. Sorry I try to learn is first time i do this.

Comment: First you do, what @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs said. As in the answer i linked. Then you do `foreach ($myPostVar as $item) { /*Do what you want in your email.*/}`. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

Comment: @AjAX. thank you! I think to start to understand. I will try ti. If you want you can answer below.

Comment: Pleasure. I hope everything works out.

Comment: @AjAX. In my case I will use `parse_str($_POST['datiform'], $myPostVar)` ad in the loop i can just do `<li>$item</li>`.  in this way i will read all the data in the string in a list.

Comment: Sounds fair. %)P

Answer (score 0):

serializing in jquery means to actually create a string var1=1&var2=234. You can simple access the data using GET['var1'] or POST['var2'] in PHP.