# Serializing Laravel blade arrays

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, forms, laravel-blade

I am working on a lengthy form in laravel blade comprising of thousands of variables. I am using an array for name attribute in form. The form is submitting fine but sometimes I have an exception in my log that "php max variable limit of input variable exceeded" and some data gets missing on my records. Exceeding php max variable limit is not going to be working for me so I decided to serialize my form data into a single variable and pass it to laravel controller where I can un-serialize and use the data.  But  I am stuck at a point where my name attribute is an array. The thing I tried so far is :

my JS function

```
function submitForm() {
    var form_data = $("#edit-form").find(".check-enabled :input").serializeArray();
    var form_obj =  {'form_data' : form_data, "_token": $('#token').val()}

    if($(".submit-input-checks:checked").length==0)
    {
        swal("Please select atleast 1 Record");
        return false;
    }

    $.post("{{route('save_opps')}}", form_obj, function (data) {

    });

}
```

in my laravel controller, I am doing like

```
public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $data = unserialize($data['form_data']);
    }
```

but its not working like submitting form directly. The blade arrays are not converted to php array. How can I achieve this? or it there any better solution.

**Edits**
[request data dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF7kd.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I PHP-unserialize a jQuery-serialized form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603/how-do-i-php-unserialize-a-jquery-serialized-form) also use `$values = []; parse_str($data['form_data'], $values);echo $values['input1'];`

Comment: @N69S no success.

Comment: do a `dd($data)` before unserializing with php

Comment: @N69S added dump to question details

Comment: I am getting "unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 18006 bytes"

Comment: @RehanZia you are still using unserialize, instead use parse_str as recommended by  N69S

Comment: @ArsiiRasheed now I am getting the error that i mentioned in question php max variable limit exceeds

Comment: @RehanZia cause the way you serialize it, it wont make it into one variable.

Comment: @RehanZia than you can do it manually, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $temp = explode('&',$request['form_data']);
        $data = [];
        foreach ($temp as $key => $value)
        {
            $pair =[];
            parse_str($value,$pair);
            foreach ($pair as $key  => $value1)
            {
                if(isset($data[$key]))
                {
                    array_push($data[$key], is_array($value1) ? $value1[0] : $value1);
                }else
                {
                    $data[$key] = [];
                    array_push($data[$key],is_array($value1) ? $value1[0] : $value1);
                }
            }

        }
     //use $data further
```