# Post with Ajax and Bootstrap Modal in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I am using `code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js` in my application, and trying to post data without reload.
It posts fine without ajax, but not with ajax script.

Controllers:

```
public function index()
{
    $tasks = Task::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(9);
    return view('empmodel', compact('tasks'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tasks = new Task;
    $tasks->t_title = $request->input('t_title');
    $tasks->project_id = $request->input('project_id');
    $tasks->save();
}
```

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/addstudent",
            data: $('#addform').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                $('#studentaddmodal').modal('hide')
                alert("data saved");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error)
                alert("Data not saved");
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/tasks', 'projects\ProjectpController@index');
Route::post('/addstudent', 'projects\ProjectpController@store');
```

When I fill integer in the field with `project_id`, alert says "data saved", but it does not appear in the database.
If I put text in `project_id` field, then the alert is as supposed to be "data not saved".
CSRF token is not missing. I am using regular bootstrap Modal.

Comment: debug your code in the store method, check what you are missing while you are storing. debug will show the exact errors or warnings..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the string that you send from the AJAX in the Controlller using [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Change the data definition of your ajax to

```
data: {
    formData: $('#addform').serialize()
}
```

and in your Controller method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    parse_str($request->formData, $output);
    $tasks = new Task;
    $tasks->t_title = $output['t_title'];
    $tasks->project_id = $output['project_id'];
    $tasks->save();
}
```

Similar Question: [How do I PHP-unserialize a jQuery-serialized form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603/how-do-i-php-unserialize-a-jquery-serialized-form)

Read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3817220/5808894