# Howto serialize an array'd checkbox in jQuery

Tags: jquery, serialization

It's pretty awkward that I couldn't find a thread with a similar problem...
Well then, let's assume I have a standard HTML form with checkboxes (that will be parsed as an array in PHP), notice the **brackets** in the name attribute:

```
<form class="myForm" action="evaluate.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your name"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="facts[]" value="1" id="fact-1"/><label for="fact-1">Fact 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="facts[]" value="2" id="fact-2"/><label for="fact-2">Fact 2</label>
    ...
</form>
```

And now I want jQuery to serialize the content of the form with:

```
alert($('.myForm').serialize());
```

The expected result would be something like this:

```
name=MyName&facts[]=1&facts=[]=2&...
```

but unfortunately it doesn't, because the brackets "[]" are escaped:

```
name=MyName&facts%5B%5D=1&facts=%5B%5D=2&...
```

Has anyone a solution for this problem except writing an own serialization script?

Comment: OK, I found a thread talking about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304518/how-to-send-serialize-form-data-using-jquery-if-the-input-element-is-an-array but there is no accepted solution. "serialize().replace('%5B%5D', '[]')" is a little risky I think.

Comment: please take some time to read the [faq]. If there isn't an answer that suits you, you'll just have to add a bounty to it. I understand that you're new and don't have the rep to assign a bounty, but it's really not all that difficult to answer a few questions and get the 50 rep necessary to open a small bounty.

Comment: k I'll heed your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or try:

```
alert(decodeURI('MyName&facts%5B%5D=1&facts=%5B%5D=2&'));
```

it will decode all escaped characters including `[]`

Comment: This is one of the handiest js functions.