# How to send a Jquery ordered list to a php script via Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem concerning Ajax and Jquery.
I have a bunch of `<li>` elements which can be sorted with Jquery. There are also hidden fields for each `li` element. These hidden fields all have the name `list[]`. This way PHP will create an array containing the content of the hidden fields.
Now I am trying to implement an autosave option. This means, every 30 seconds or so the order of the li elements will automatically be saved in a mysql database.
My try until now is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
autosave(); 
});

function autosave() 
{ 
var t = setTimeout("autosave()", 500);
    $.ajax( 
    { 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "autosave.php", 
        data: "list[]="  + list, 
        cache: false,
            success: function(message)
            {   
                $("#autosave").empty().append(message);
            }

    }); 
}
```

For testing purposes the autosave.php will just output a text just to see whether the jquery works. So I found out that the problem is the `data: "list[]=" + list`. This wont send my values from the hidden fields to the autosave.php.

Does anybody have an idea what is my mistake and how I can send the array list to my autosave.php?

Thanks for help
phpheini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `list` like this:

```
var list = $("[name='list[]']").map(function(){
    return this.name + "=" + this.value;
}).get().join("&");
```

Then assign `list` to `data` directly:

```
$.ajax({  
    ...
    data: list,
    ...
});
```

**Edit:** Forgive me if this is a review for you, but let's get down to the basics.  In an HTTP POST request, the post body is sent as a collection of key value pairs.  Keys and values are separated with `=` and the pairs are separated with `&`.

```
firstName=Fred&lastName=Jones&town=Bedrock
```

As you already understand, to have PHP convert the posted elements to an array, give the key a `[]` suffix.  To send two arrays to PHP, list1 (1, 2, 3) and list2 ("a", "b", "c"), your post body would look like this:

```
list1[]=1&list1[]=2&list1[]=3&list2[]=a&list2[]=b&list2[]=c
```

Now, when you make a call to `$.ajax`, `data` can be either the post body string, or an object that jQuery will serialize into a post body string.  AFAIK, jQuery would not be able to serialize an object into the string above, so we need to create it ourselves.  If your form fields are already set up correctly, and you want to submit all of those fields, the answer is easy: `$("#myForm").serialize()` will give you the post body string you want.

```
$.ajax({  
    ...
    data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
    ...
});
```

One caveat is that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323044) suggests you may need to un-escape the `[]` using `$("#myForm").serialize().replace(/%5b%5d/ig, "[]")`, but I'm not sure that's really necessary.

If using `.serialize()` is not an option, then you'll need to manually construct the string. Follow the pattern in my first example above.  Just make sure that you have `key=value` pairs separated by `&` with arrays having a `[]` suffix on the key.

Comment: `data` should be a collection of `name=value` pairs, separated by `&`.  You can construct that string manually, or you can probably use `$("#myForm").serialize()` instead, but you may have to also replace the escaped brackets with actual brackets per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323044).

Comment: So do I have to put the & into your first code snippet or the second one? How do I connect the two lists in the second snippet? data: list + list2 doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
dataType: 'json',
data: { list:MyListOfElements },
```

where `MyListOfElements` is your array and `list` is the key used in your PHP code to retrieve the data.

Comment: So in this case it would be data: { list:list }, wouldnt it be?
This way it doesnt work...