# How do I unserialize a jQuery-serialize value in php

Tags: php, jquery

I am able to send jquery serialize value in php file. But I can't unserialize jquery serialize value in php. Now Please, tell me How do I unserialize jquery serialize value in php file. my jquery code is :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // index.php
    function get(){
        $('#age').hide();
        $.post('data.php',{ name: $('form').serialize() },

    function (output){
        $('#age').html(output).fadeIn(1000);
    });
    }
</script>
```

data.php file is:

```
<?php
echo var_dump(unserialize($_POST['name']));
?>
```

I use above code for unserialize jquery serialize value but I don't get any result

Answer (score 4):

How about simplify it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// index.php
function get(){
    $('#age').hide();
    $.post('data.php',$('form').serialize(),
        function (output){
          $('#age').html(output).fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
</script>
```

and in data.php

```
<?php
    $name=$_POST;
    echo var_dump($name);  
?>
```

Using serialize here is same as a form submit.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should not have to unserialise the data.

If the data is being passed as the for parameters, then the following will suffice.

```
$form_values = $_POST;
print_r($form_values);
```

However, sometimes you might want to pass serialised string as one of the fields of the form. In this case, you can use something like the following:

```
$form_values = $_POST;
$serialised_form_value = $form_values['some_field_from_form'];
parse_str($serialised_form_value, $field_value);
print_r($field_value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are sending a JSON object to your PHP script so you should use [`json_decode()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

---

Ultimately you are not getting any results because the `$_POST` data is interpreted as a string, granted a string with JSON syntax but still nothing but a simple string to PHP.  To get the contents you must use the `json_decode()` function linked to above.  By default it will return a `stdClass` object, pass `true` to the second parameter to return an associative array

```
// return stdClass or null on error
$jsonData = json_decode($_POST['name']);

// return associative array or null on error
$jsonData = json_decode($_POST['name'], true);
```

You should make sure to check if there is a value stored in `$_POST['name']` before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You need not unserialize anything. The function's name is a bit misleading. jQuery's `.serialize()` creates a string representation of the form just like as if it was sent by a regular form, for example, calling `.serialize()` on the following form:

```
<input name="a" value="foo" />
<input name="b" value="bar" />
```

will result in this string:

```
a=foo&b=bar
```

If you modify your ajax call to:

```
$.post('data.php', $('form').serialize(), function (output) {...});
```

Your form will simply be in `$_POST`, ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

sorry reposted my answer [100% work for my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13951516/1540635)
work correctly
jquery =>

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
            $.post(baseUrl+'/ajax.php',
                    {action:'saveData',data:data},
                    function( data ) {
                        alert(data);
                    });
```

php =>

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $searcharray);
    echo ('<PRE>');print_r($searcharray);echo ('</PRE>');
```

output =>

```
[query] => 
[search_type] => 0
[motive_note] => 
[id_state] => 1
[sel_status] => Array
    (
        [8] => 0
        [7] => 1
    )
```

and You can do whatever what you want like with "$searcharray" variable data,
thanks to [Aridane https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792603](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11280554/1540635)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The serialized array is an array of name:xxx, value:....

Here's what I did to convert it to a PHP object.

```
 $data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
 $obj=new \StdClass;
     foreach ($data as $row){
      $key=$row->name;
      $value=$row->value;
      $obj->$key=$value;
  }
```

So, here, it is iterating through the JQuery serialized array, and creating a PHP object property with the "name" value, and giving the property a value with the "value" value.