# not receiving data in php codeigniter when sending ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to send data by post using ajax (with codeigniter) and I don't know why but I don't receive anything...

This is how I send it:

```
var sendData = $('#formContact').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo base_url()?>/intranet/update/updateProfile',
    data: sendData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) 
    {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

and this is an example of my form:

```
<form id="formContact" action="update" method="POST">
    <input class="headInput" type="text" name="userName" value="Tito"/>
    <input class="headInput" type="text" name="userLastName" value="Lancreo"/>
    <input class="headInput" type="text" name="phone[]" value="666666"/>
    <input class="headInput" type="text" name="phone[]" value="111111"/>
    <input class="headInput" type="text" name="phone[]" value="222222"/>
</form>
```

And when I debug it, I always get 0...

```
[false, false, Array[0], false, null]
```

My controller:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

//1 way
$ret=$this->input->post();

//2 way        
$return=$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);

//3 way
$all=$_POST;
json_encode($all);

//4 way
$contact=$this->input->post("userName");

//return everything...
$var[0]=$return;
$var[1]=$contact;
$var[2]=$all;
$var[3]=$ret;
$var[4]=$data;
echo json_encode($var);
```

How can I fix it??

Comment: what is inside `sendData` ?

Comment: Hope $.ajax in document ready

Comment: may be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395354/jquery-ajax-readystate-0-responsetext-status-0-statustext-error

Comment: in sendData I have my form serialize, I update it.
And yes, is in document.ready.

Comment: the same, it doesn't work

Comment: and to clarify the ajax part is inside `$(document).ready(function() {` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

The problem was not to replace with:

```
serialize().replace(/%5B%5D/g, '[]');
```

But I think it's usefull...

My problem was that I'm using a library for internationalization (https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n) and I must add language to my url, even if I change my routes.php

```
url: '<?php echo base_url()?>en/intranet/update/updateProfile'
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

The issue, as it seems, Is the serialize itself.

As can be seen here :

[How to send serialize form data using JQuery if the input element is an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304518/how-to-send-serialize-form-data-using-jquery-if-the-input-element-is-an-array)

Serialize has an issue with an array in the input fields, It replaces the square barckets :

The fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/3vr0dtgn/

from my fiddle:

```
data = $('form').serialize();
$('div').append(data);
```

Using the stackoverflow I supplied above gives the solution(regex replacing certain elements)

Comment: As I have tested it. It works without any issue it's just an encoding done by serialize.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Well I did not invent the wheel, For me strictly fixing the encoding with a regex solved the issue.

Comment: It doesn't work... It is true that it replace it, but in my controller, I still have no data in _POST. But I've just found the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear, Answer your own question for future generations :)