# posing an array from jQuery to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

I posted a smaller to this yesterday and was shown how to do this but it doesn't work and the user never got back to me and I have been working on the same problem for hours.

I am trying to post a checkbox array from jQuery to php, when I run my code nothing seems to happen and when I try var_dump($_POST) this is all I get

Comment: Well for starters, where is the checkbox array? All i see is 5 hidden inputs with no values.

Comment: Please do not ask new questions just because one person does not return immediately.

Comment: oops posted the wrong one, hold on

Comment: Also when you post, remove the snippet comment after clicking TIDY if the snippet does not actually run

Comment: I think you just have a several forms on the page so $('form').serialize wouldn't work as expected

Comment: i don't see any *.submit-button*  any class in your submit button

Comment: oh yeah I changed it in my actually code when running it

Comment: what is your jquery version ?

Comment: can you show the right code of myindex.php page

Comment: @Beck - we really need a [mcve] - you are wasting our time with not showing the actual code or HTML of what you are running

Comment: I am showing the actually HTML code

Comment: How can you receive "Save Result" when there is no "Save Result" anywhere in your code?

Comment: have a look at the php

Answer (score -1):

Using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304518/how-to-send-serialize-form-data-using-jquery-if-the-input-element-is-an-array) as a reference, it seems that jQuery doesn't handle arrays too well. You can use to snippet from the accepted answer and it should work just fine.

```
serialize().replace(/%5B%5D/g, '[]')
```

Answer (score -1):

- Change the submit to a button or better use the form's submit event
- why data-type html?
- Your php does not seem to react to the serialised data but returns a button...

try my code here: http://plungjan.name/SO/sport.php

I am not unravelling the check box array - that is up to you

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['saved'])) {
  echo "saved"; exit(0);
}
else if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
  echo var_dump($_POST["sport"]); exit(0);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sports quiz</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#myForm').on("submit", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // cancel submit
    var $form = $(this);
    if ($("[type=checkbox]:checked").length ==0) {
      alert("Please check one or more");
      return false;
    }
    var formData = $form.serializeArray();
    formData.push({name:"Submit",value:"submit"}); // note I changed the name from submit to Submit
    $.post('sport.php',formData, function(data) {
      console.log("Data",data);
      if (confirm('You want to save \n' + data + ' as your sport?')) {
        formData = $form.serializeArray();
        formData.push({name:"saved",value:"saved"});
        $.post('sport.php',formData,function(data) {
          console.log("Saved Data",data);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form id="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Football">Football<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Rugby">Rugby<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Golf">Golf<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="Basketball">Basketball<br>
  <br> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still no joy with it

Comment: what does what mean?

Comment: when I run the console there are no errors appearing

Comment: I did a var_dump($_POST) and get array(1) { ["save"]=> string(11) "Save Result" }

Comment: tried that but no luck with it, I have a var_dump in the code I didn't post

Comment: echo '<input type="submit" id="save" name="save" value="Save Result">';

Comment: I echo it to check if it is being posted or not

Comment: console.log doesn't seem to show anything and I get no errors displaying in the console

Comment: why is this? any idea how I would get it to run?

Comment: i think it isn't picking up the form, could it be because the form is on another page?

Comment: Whoever voted this down, please tell me why so I can improve the answer?